# Modifiying xAxsis by displaying specific date/time in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here is my code below

```
 xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',[enter link description here][1]
                labels: {

                    style: {
                        color: '#525151',
                        font: '14px Arial',
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },

                 formatter: function () {

                    var mychartdate = reversegridarrayFORUNDEFINE(st_time_formated_CHART);
                    if (chartvariable <= ta) {
                            if (mychartdate[chartvariable] == 0) {

                                // var mycharttime = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P', this.value);
                                var mycharttime = Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%P',this.value);

                                chartvariable++;
                                return mycharttime;
                            }
                            else {
                                var mycharttimer = Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e %Y %H:%M:%P', mychartdate[chartvariable] + this.value);
                                chartvariable++;
                                return mycharttimer;
                            }
                        }

       //return mycharttime;

                    }


                },[enter link description here][2]
```

I am trying to display different dateformats based on if-else but it 
As you see in the picture below ,  it doesn't display last four scale in xAxsis . Eventohugh it completes if-else statement for each valriable and then it keeps going to loop again inside the function four times.
But if I don't use if-else inside the function , it displays well but displays only time which I don't want

Any help appreciated.

[my js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en9atkz2/)

Comment: Could you post live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately can't because  it is part of a big project but the idea is simple. Using if-else statement doesn't work properly in xAxsis .It misses some scales in xAxsis lane. There is one similar example here. http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/PyYnF/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/en9atkz2/

Comment: Your first fiddle wasn't including highcharts.js and the data was out of order, but otherwise it only displays the 2 requested data points on the xAxis.  Is there another problem? http://jsfiddle.net/PyYnF/55/

Comment: Please go with my second jsfiddle   jsfiddle.net/en9atkz2

Comment: in arraylist there is st_date for some data that I want to display it with time in xAxis .I have to use if-else because some others st_date is="undefined" so how can I display st_date on xAxis?

Comment: If you want to display st_date as time type value you should parse it to JavaScript timestamp format.